# Past vs. Present

Tags: discussion, rules

My question is: Have the rules of Stack Overflow changed at any point since its creation?

I ask this because, prior to joining SO a few months ago, I researched and Googled several of the questions I had on C#. The SO results that appeared were questions that did *not* have 'code that proved an attempt', but rather a simple question that the user had and a direct answer.

Rarely do I see on questions earlier on in SO's life comments such as "What've you tried?" or "Show us what you have so far". I found that a little misleading, as when I first joined my earlier questions didn't consist of code to prove my attempts.

I saw previous questions, formed a general idea of how to ask it based on such, and asked. Have the rules changed?

Comment: The short answer is: yes, the rules have changed over time. We've learned about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: And we still are, of course. That's a continuous process.

Comment: Also I think that the very first posts in Stack Overflow didn't have.. Stack Overflow reference :) For example, when you type in Google "How to compare Strings in Java" you'll be referenced to Stack Overflow and not to the JLS. I'm not sure I explained myself well, but I hope the point is clear.

Comment: This question is very good. I researched a lot about what people ask in tag *Android* and I noticed that 70-80% of questions are duplicates or simply have another interpretation. I saw many old answers, where questions were very simple, as author said, but now for similar sort of questions there are 2 scenarios: it will be closed or hardly downvoted with comment such as "google first" or similar. I haven't met this kinds of comments in old questions, where question was: *How to use Set in Java* and don't say there was no documentation and bunch of links.

Comment: Maybe it's because internet changed since then, these questions are 7-8 years old. The internet has significantly grown since then, more and more resources were added and it's pretty much easier to search for things. According to stats, it's more than X2 users since then!

Comment: This must be a duplicate. A similar question was asked less than three months ago. Did nobody find the link to that (me inclusive)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Rarely do I see on questions earlier on in SO's life comments such as "What've you tried?"

There were a *lot* of those comments.  So much so that the phrase is blocked, you cannot type that as a comment anymore.  Well, if you type it like "What have you tried", the blocking code isn't otherwise smart enough to understand that "What've" is the same as "What have".

What you are probably seeing is that a lot of those comments have been deleted, usually by somebody flagging the comment as "Rude".

So there no such rule, you are entitled to not have tried anything at all and just throw spaghetti at the wall and hope it will stick.  Such a question won't necessarily be considered helpful of course, SO users tend to downvote if the odds that the question will be useful to other programmers are low.  The less you cooked the spaghetti, the lower odds it will stick.

Another thing to keep in mind is that SO gets a *lot* of questions, almost a quarter of a million a month as of late.  You are competing with many other programmers that have questions, many of them don't get an answer at all.  This is over-compensated, there are plenty of questions that *do* contain a snippet but the code is just completely unhelpful to demonstrate the issue.  Don't do that either, follow the [Help Center guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also note that many of the old bad questions, including those that lacks a demonstration of what the user was trying to do, have since been deleted.  That can give the false impression that there were less bad questions asked in the past than there actually were.

Answer (score 6):

Facts:

- Stack Overflow was launched in 2008
- Prior to Stack Overflow, there was no <strike>such</strike> similar resource for programmers
- [~3.276M answers / year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201651/how-many-questions-and-answers-are-asked-in-one-day-at-stack-overflow) added to StackOverflow
- Internet growth statistics show there are more than double the users on the web since 2008

The very first posts on Stack Overflow didn't have Stack-Overflow-like qualities. For example, when you search on Google "How to compare Strings in Java" you'll be sent to Stack Overflow and not to the JLS.

Imagine a new language that has limited resources on the web, and you want to ask a question but there are not enough references to consult. You'll ask that question in Stack Overflow, and in the meantime many other users are having the same problem, and they will be referenced to *your* question on Stack Overflow. Hopefully right to questions that had an answer from a user that came across the same issue.

The internet has grown in 7-8 years and has become accessible to more people. The resources on the internet have also significantly increased and it is easier to find what you are looking for on the internet today.

Having said this, it's reasonable to think that there are many highly upvoted posts from the past that would receive a tremendous amount of downvotes if asked today. So yes, the rules have changed on Stack Overflow during its history.

Comment: Stating that there were no resources for programmers prior to SO is just flat out wrong.  You can argue that SO was a much better resource than its predecessors, although even that is both subjective and dependent on the individual.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say there were no resources, I said in general the internet has grown since then, including the resources.

Comment: `Prior to Stack Overflow, there was no resource for programmers`  You said *exactly* that.

Comment: @Servy That was invalid edit by other user. **I** *didn't* say that.

Comment: @GEOCHET you totally changed what I meant. There's a huge difference between "there was no resource" and "there was no such resource". Also there's a difference between "it's" and "its".

Comment: I'd suggest clarifying that statement further, at least to some degree.

Comment: @Servy English is not my native language, sorry :( I'll try to better rephrase it and clarify my point.

Comment: The edit I made is not what caused the objection. Your original post made very little sense and is better suited as a comment than an answer. Taking the word 'such' out of the sentence in question is just removing a completely superfluous word. The problem with your sentence is not whether or not it contains 'such', it is your assertion that the resource did not exist. By rolling back instead of fixing your assertion (which as an editor, I don't aim to do), you destroyed valid edits for no reason and made your answer lower quality.

Comment: @GEOCHET Also, it's "Stack Overflow" (with a space), not "StackOverflow." I know the logo is misleading (I used to think it was all one word, too), but you can see the correct spelling in several of the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @GEOCHET By "no such resource" I meant "resource like Stack Overflow". Excuse me if it's not clear, maybe I literally translated from Arabic (it makes sense in Arabic), please edit it if you feel you can improve it, but as I said, editing it to "no resource" completely changes its meaning.

Comment: @GEOCHET Also I kept many parts of your edit, thanks for that.

Comment: @GEOCHET Uh... Maroun _did not_ roll back your edits. He fixed a few things he felt were wrong with it, such as the name issue that ThisSuitIsBlackNot mentioned and the "it's" before history that Maroun mentioned changing back. He also added back the word "such" which is perfectly fine. But he didn't roll the edits back, he only fixed a few mistakes your edit made. As for "such" in this context, it's used to mean "no similar resource" not "no resource at all" which I understood just fine. So it's not _completely_ bad, but could be improved.